# SQL Server: Transpose Column to Rows

Tags: transpose

I have table data like this.

```
    Seq,File
    ----------
    1,'100001-01-02-03-05.xls'
    2,'100002-01-02-03-09.doc'
```

I need to convert the above table structure to individual rows like this, How to combine the normal Pivot to this format.

```
     Seq, ID, File
     --------------
     1, 100001-01,'100001-01-02-03-05.xls'
     2, 100001-02,'100001-01-02-03-05.xls'
     3, 100001-03,'100001-01-02-03-05.xls'
     4, 100001-05,'100001-01-02-03-05.xls'
     5, 100002-01,'100002-01-02-03-09.doc'
     6, 100002-02,'100002-01-02-03-09.doc'
     7, 100002-03,'100002-01-02-03-09.doc'
     8, 100002-09,'100002-01-02-03-09.doc'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CROSS APPLY and the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
select 
  seq,
  substring(filename, 0, charindex('-',filename)+1) + value,
  filename
from files
  cross apply string_split(
    substring(
      filename, 
      charindex('-',filename) + 1, 
      charindex('.',filename)-charindex('-',filename)-1
    ),
    '-'
  )
```

[link to fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=72fb1d5b0798d360c16492aedbb016ca)

Details about how the query works:

1. In the select clause, `substring(filename, 0, charindex('-',filename)+1)` is responsible for getting the ID prefix, e.g. `100002-`.
2. In the select clause, `value` is provided by the string_split function, e.g. `01-02-03-05` is split into four rows with values `01`, `02`, `03` and `05`
3. The last substring provides input value for the string_split function by taking the substring of the filename between the first `-` and the last `.`, e.g. `100001-01-02-03-05.xls` becomes `01-02-03-05`